# Session is not being recognized on first run

Tags: php

Is there a better way of doing this? I am setting a session in my initial code and referring to it straight after and it doesn't get recognized on the first iteration.

The user enters an activation key and the code checks it against the database, if it is there then it places the key into a session for further use later on. It doesn't work from when the browser first opens but always works thereafter...which is very strange.

Create session:

```
session_start();
....
$_SESSION['SESS_KEY'] = $member['key'];    
session_write_close();
header("location: http://example1.com")
exit();
```

Check Session:

```
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_KEY']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_KEY']) == '')) {
    header("location: http://example2.com");
 }
```

It may be the way I am using session_start() and header, but I am at a brick wall and have spent far too long trying to understand it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't forget to `exit()` after `header("location: http://example2.com");` too :-)

Comment: Create session and Check session are two different files. Check session is called when accessing a page I only want accessed if there is a valid key being used.

Comment: What's the order-of-operations for that script? It's normal for session cookies to not be there in a fresh browser instance - session cookies are set to be "session" only (e.g. delete when browser exits).

Comment: 1. Create session (checks for valid key and creates session)
2. Goes to the next page (which in turn calls Check Session)

Answer (score 0):

that is the normal behavior, it is sent in request header on the next request(s) from client browser,once created. you can't access the just created value of a session variable on the same page. in this scenario you can just create a variable and access it if you need, variable are accessible across different files in single request processing in PHP.

Comment: uh, what? session data is stored server side. The only thing sent to the client is the session ID cookie. You can store data in $_SESSION anytime you want and it'll be available immediately and in subsequent script runs, assuming the cookie is working properly.

Comment: @MarcB this happened long ago. see your request header, when session is set, through a tool like fiddler etc

Comment: I've used similar code in other projects without any issue. The plot thickens, when I leave out the check session it never gets set however many times its run but it always gets set after the second run if I include it...

Comment: when you do session_start(), if there's no session cookie received, PHP will generate a new ID and set the cookie in the headers of the response of the script that's starting the session. It's not on "the next" request, because by HTTP's statelessness, the next request will have no relationship to the first request, EXCEPT via that session cookie.